# chkdsk constantly reports file and/or MFT corruption, but it only ever affects VSS

Tags: windows, filesystems, chkdsk, vss

I'm having the strangest issue with chkdsk constantly reporting errors on a Windows 10 system, but there are almost no user-facing problems.  The only thing it ever seems to cause an issue with is VSS (and consequentially, system restore and other backup platforms that depend on VSS).

I have to run chkdsk a half dozen times to actually clear the errors, and they just return almost immediately.  Sometimes it finds corrupted files, sometimes it's MFT corruption, sometimes both.

Windows has no problems booting or generally running.  The BIOS is up to date.  The chipset and SATA drivers have been updated.  I've replaced the drive.  All other diagnostics pass (SMART, memtest, sfc, DISM) and report no errors or failures.

I would think that if it were a failing SATA controller or some other circuitry on the board, there would be all sorts of obscure and random errors, but the only thing that doesn't work is VSS.

What could be causing this?

Comment: “What could be causing this?” - Bad sectors but fewer than the firmware considers a problem but that’s only true today. You replaced the drive with a new one?

Comment: @Ramhound: correct, the drive was replaced with a brand new one and the issue persisted.

Comment: Is your system running multiple operating systems?

Comment: @Ramhound: no, just Windows 10.

Comment: Is Hybrid Suspend enabled or disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound: hybrid suspend is disabled